# UITableView dataSource from Class object within a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift3

I would like to see each `allItems` for each object in `inventory` to be displayed in each row. As it is now, where I have written `indexPathOfCollectionView`, there's a 0 to see that it is actually working, but I don't know which variable should I write to be able to see each `allItems` from the `inventory`.

```
var inventory = [Item]()

class Item {

    var name: String!
    var allItems: [String]!

    init(name: String, allItems: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.allItems = allItems
    }

}
```

Collection Cell:

```
class ItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var inventory = [Item]()

    @IBOutlet weak var testTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    func configureCell(_ inventory: Item) {

        nameLabel.text = inventory[indexPath.row]
        testTableView.dataSource = self

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return inventory[indexPathOfCollectionView*].allItems.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemsCell")

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "ItemsCell")
    }

        cell.textLabel?.text = inventory[indexPathOfCollection*].allItems[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

This is in the `viewController`

```
    class VC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return inventory.count

        }

        func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

            return 1

        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCellItem", for: indexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell

            let it: Item!
            it = inventory[indexPath.row]

            cell.configureCell(it)

            return cell

        }

    }
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-If-oRJP7-cSGFJYnVOLUt2YXM/view?usp=sharing) of what I've got

Comment: what do you exactly want?

Comment: To be able to display each individual unique array inside `Item` in the `tableView` inside the `collectionViewCell`. As it is now, it displays only the first object as I mentioned writing 0 in inventory[0].allItems[indexPath.row]. That 0 is the problem and I cannot see any possible solution

Comment: try `inventory[indexPath.row]` instead of `inventory[indexPathOfCollection*]`

Comment: I get the same result.. It still shows the objects in the first `inventory`. Also, I get an error if I put `indexPath.row` in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: In your class `Item` why have you made the array `Inventory`? And in your `configureCell` you aren't passing the model?

Comment: Ah! Sorry, it's corrected now. I pass the model, but in my actual code it's there, otherwise I would get an error. `inventory` is a global variable and I get the data from adding objects in another `viewController`. I get the right `allItems` only for the first object, which is index 0, but I am looking for a way to set it to retrieve `allItems for each new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, from your class `Item` remove the `Inventory` array as it is not needed **inside** your model. It should be present with the `UIViewController`. Making the following changes ought to make your code run as required!

Change your `UIViewController` to-

```
class VC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var inventory = [Item]()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         return inventory.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCellItem", for: indexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell

        //Just pass the model inside of the array!
        cell.itemsList = inventory[indexPath.item]

        cell.configureCell()

        return cell
    }
}
```

And inside your `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
class ItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var itemsList : Item!

    @IBOutlet weak var testTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {

         super.awakeFromNib()

         testTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func configureCell() {

        testTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemsList.allItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemsCell")

        if(cell == nil){

             cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "ItemsCell")
        }

        //get array of strings from inside that particular model!
        cell.textLabel?.text = itemsList.allItems[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I was a little bit confused when I was working with your answer, but in the end I managed to make it work! numberOfRowsInSection worked with itemsList.allItems.count, as itemsList is a class, and cellForRowAt is itemsList.allItems. Thank you for enlightening the way!

Comment: Ahh yes good catch! That was quite silly of me to miss that! :)